# The command exited with code -1 monogame 3.5 and VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, monogame

I installed **Windows 10** in my computer with **Visual Studio 2015 Community** and **MonoGame 3.5**.

When I built a new project i recieved a error exit code -1 a below:

[image: The command exited with code -1]

I googled for this error code but no luck. I need a help, could someone please help fix this error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason.

It's because MonoGame's Content Pipeline is 64bit only and my OS is 32bit.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To "close the topic" as to said, you can accept the answer by clicking the tick on the left.